# Do outdoor outlet covers have standard sizes / screw placement?

Tags: receptacle, outdoor

Do outdoor outlet covers have standard sizes / screw placement?

I would like to replace the cover pictured below (preferably without having to replace the whole box).  The cover has BWF on the front, but I'm not finding anything similar branded BWF.  Should I be able to simply measure the dimensions and the width between the screws and find another brand that will fit?

[image]

Comment: A search for 'bwf wet location outlet cover' sure turns up a lot of BWF labeled products. Take measurements and go down to your local store.

Answer (score 2):

Those boxes are very standard and so are the covers. Squirt some penetrating oil on those two screws and let it set a bit before trying to remove them. You don't want to twist off the heads or you'll be replacing the box. Remove the cover and take it to the home store with you if it will make you feel better to match the cover.

Check to make sure that you can't pry the existing cover back into the frame. It looks like the pin is still there and maybe the cover was hit while open and jarred the cover off

Comment: I can get the cover into the frame easily.  It just won't stay there.  It "flops" open and closed, whereas the covers on all the other outlets are very stiff (in a good way).

Comment: @Zack Ok, time to replace.... it was just a thought.